# JOIN expression not supported in MsAccess table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I currently have a table called `RECHEADS` as shown below. I am looking to remove duplicates that share the same `CUSQ`, `CCNI`, `DATV` and `PROD` values but have a subsequent `SREFQ` number.

So, in this case, I would like to remove `NAT 785`, `NAT 786` and `METRO 3206`

```
CUSQ  |  CCNI          |  DATV      | SREFQ      | PROD
----    -----    -----   ------   ------ 
14    | James FLETCHER | 13/03/2017 | NAT 784    |00018-144X
14    | James FLETCHER | 13/03/2017 | NAT 785    |00018-144X
14    | James FLETCHER | 13/03/2017 | NAT 786    |00018-144X
19    | DENISE FORZANI | 14/03/2017 | METRO 3205 | 05239-01P
19    | DENISE FORZANI | 14/03/2017 | METRO 3206 | 05239-01P
19    | DENISE FORZANI | 14/03/2017 | METRO 3207 | 05239-01Q
```

I have tried the following but the inner query gives me

> JOIN expression not supported

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE SREFQ IN 
    (
        SELECT t1.SREFQ
        FROM RECHEADS AS t1
            INNER JOIN RECHEADS AS t2 ON       
                t2.cusq = t1.cusq AND
                t2.ccni = t1.ccni AND
                t2.datv = t1.datv AND
                right(t2.srefq, len(t2.srefq)-instr(t2.srefq, " ")) + 1 = right(t2.srefq, len(t2.srefq)-instr(t2.srefq, " "))
    );
```

Comment: Did you type this correctly: `t2.cusq = t1.cus1` ?

Comment: @Manngo My bad, I've now corrected this

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around the expressions: `(t2.cusq = t1.cusq)`. There is a bug mentioned concerning this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM RECHEADS
WHERE SREFQ IN 
(
    select r1.SREFQ
    from RECHEADS r1
    where exists (select * 
           from RECHEADS r2 
           where r2.CUSQ = r1.CUSQ and 
           r2.CCNI = r1.CCNI and 
           r2.DATV = r1.DATV and 
           r2.PROD = r1.PROD and 
           right(r1.srefq, len(r1.srefq)-instr(r1.srefq, " ")) = right(r2.srefq, len(r2.srefq)-instr(r2.srefq, " ")) + 1)
)
```

Actually, your query should work, you just forgot to add in the `PROD` comparison in the join (and you need to enclose the whole `ON` part in parentheses:

```
DELETE FROM RECHEADS
WHERE SREFQ IN 
    (
        SELECT t1.SREFQ
        FROM RECHEADS AS t1
        INNER JOIN RECHEADS AS t2 ON
        (     
                t2.cusq = t1.cusq AND
                t2.ccni = t1.ccni AND
                t2.datv = t1.datv AND
                t2.prod = t1.prod AND
                right(t2.srefq, len(t2.srefq)-instr(t2.srefq, " ")) + 1 = right(t1.srefq, len(t1.srefq)-instr(t1.srefq, " "))
        )
    );
```

**Update**

If your SREFQ column can contain more than one space, then you'll need to extract the numeric portion a different way (by looking for the " " character from the right instead of from the left).  Just replace `instr` with `instrrev`:

```
DELETE FROM RECHEADS
WHERE SREFQ IN 
    (
        SELECT t1.SREFQ
        FROM RECHEADS AS t1
        INNER JOIN RECHEADS AS t2 ON
        (     
                t2.cusq = t1.cusq AND
                t2.ccni = t1.ccni AND
                t2.datv = t1.datv AND
                t2.prod = t1.prod AND
                right(t2.srefq, len(t2.srefq)-instrrev(t2.srefq, " ")) + 1 = right(t1.srefq, len(t1.srefq)-instrrev(t1.srefq, " "))
        )
    );
```

Comment: No joy with the second it complains of "Syntax error in FROM clause". The first solution technically works although I get "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression" most likely due to srefq being a string value I am not handling correctly.

Comment: I forgot the `AND` after `t2.prod = t1.prod`.  Also, the right-hand side of the last join comparison should reference `t1` instead of `t2`.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I've copied and pasted the second solution exactly and it runs for me.

Comment: The second now works and. Only problem is they both give me a data type mismatch. I think this is due to my data. CUSQ is of type Text, CCNI is of type Text, DATV is of type Date/Time, SREFQ is of type Text and PROD is of type Text.

Comment: That's strange.  What data type is SREFQ?  Is it Short Text?  You might try wrapping the `right` functions in `CInt` to convert them to integers before comparing them.  `CInt(right(t2.srefq, len(t2.srefq)-instr(t2.srefq, " "))) + 1 = CInt(right(t1.srefq, len(t1.srefq)-instr(t1.srefq, " ")))`

Comment: You must have values of SREFQ in your table that have more than one space in them.  Your expression is extracting the numeric portion of SREFQ by looking for the first space, but if the field has more than one space, you aren't going to get a number.

Comment: Here is an example which appears very much to be a space character NAT 787. Perhaps I could take this condition out of as the existing fields alone might be sufficient ? I am guessing this would simple be SELECT t1.prod
        FROM RECHEADS AS t1
        INNER JOIN RECHEADS AS t2 ON
        (     
                t2.cusq = t1.cusq AND
                t2.ccni = t1.ccni AND
                t2.datv = t1.datv AND
                t2.prod = t1.prod )

Comment: If any SREFQ has more than one space, the query will bomb.  I've updated the answer.